Apply Bill and Journal Entry to a Vendor Bill Payment Using CSV Import
Created a Import File which contains External ID ,Date ,Bill ID, Vendor ID ,Foreign Amount ,Currency Exchange Rate. Subsidiary ,A/P and Account were given in the field mapping .Bill amount is given as positive values and Journal entry value is given as negative value.
Expected Result :
Bill payment will be generated and applied with journal and bill just like the manual method
Current Result:
When the csv import is done, the bill payment is not created and the journal is applied to the corresponding bill.
